# flattening an array of arrays into a single array that has all the elements of the original arrays 'by recursion'

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have done it by reduce
but I wanna do it by **recursion** and console prints error *TypeError: arr[0].concat is not a function*

```
let arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
// Your code here.
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

let arr = arrays.reduce((acc, current, Index, arr) => {
  return acc.concat(current);
}, []);
console.log(arr);

function flattening(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 1) return arr;
  else return flattening(arr[0].concat(arr[1]));
}
console.log(flattening(arrays));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concat the first element of the array *outside* of the call to `flattening`, and then you can pass the rest of the subarrays to `flattening`. Keep the function signature of `flattening` the same wherever it's called - its argument should accept an array of arrays (but `flattening(arr[0].concat(arr[1]))` results in passing in only a flat array, which isn't right).

```js
const arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
function flattening(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 1) return [];
  else return arr[0].concat(flattening(arr.slice(1)));
}
console.log(flattening(arrays));
```

or

```js
const arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
function flattening([arr1, ...rest]) {
  return !rest.length
    ? arr1
    : arr1.concat(flattening(rest));
}
console.log(flattening(arrays));
```